# Graphite Network interface monitoring

Tags: monitoring, graphite

I'm trying to monitor my network usage with Graphite but I can't figure out how to do this, could you help me please?

In addition to this, I would like to monitor some other services, as nginx, mysql, etc,..

Thanks for your help!

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse there are multiple solutions possible. The solution I'm using is [collectd](http://collectd.org/). With collectd you can collect statistic data from plugins in rrd files. It has a lot of plugins like network, nginx and mysql.
It does not generate graphs by itself, but there are multiple ways to generate graphs. One of them is to send the collected data to graphite with the [graphite plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aWrite_Graphite).